# Combine the results of two expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to compose the results of two Linq Expressions. The result I would like composed would be the composition of both return objects.

```
Expression<Func<Person, User>> basicUser = t => new User() { Name = t.FirstName };
Expression<Func<Person, User>> detailedUser = t => Execute basicUser and add the following  assignments { DOB = t.DOB };
```

WHERE detailedUser inherits so to speak all of the logic in basicUser and sets the DOB property of the User object.

This would be used like so:

```
context.CreateObjectSet<Persons>().Where(p => p.PersonType == User).Select<Person, User>(detailedUser);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about the result you want to have. Please provide more information on that

Comment: Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749576/modifying-lambda-expression/4760665#4760665 The second answer shows how to and 2 lambda expressions together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to rebuild the expression to add the field.

Assuming these expressions will not be complex and the `basicUser` expression will always be in that form, you could just alter the expression to add a new binding.  You can do that with the help of a simple visitor.

```
public class AddDobBindingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression parameter;

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        parameter = node.Parameters.Single();
        return base.VisitLambda(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
    {
        var member = typeof(User).GetProperty("DOB");
        var newBindings = new[]
        {
            Expression.Bind(member, Expression.Property(parameter, "DOB")),
        };
        var updatedNode = node.Update(
            node.NewExpression,
            node.Bindings.Concat(newBindings));
        return base.VisitMemberInit(updatedNode);
    }
}
```

Then to apply the changes:

```
Expression<Func<Person, User>> basicUser = person => new User()
{
    Name = person.FirstName
};
var detailedUser = (Expression<Func<Person, User>>)new AddDobBindingVisitor()
    .Visit(basicUser);
// detailedUser:
//     person => new User()
//     {
//         Name = person.FirstName,
//         DOB = person.DOB
//     }
```