# C# Change Return Value of Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

Some background: this is simply me playing with `Expression` objects for the first time and trying to simplify something I may use in one of our applications. I've been a C# developer for over 10 years, but never had reason to jump into expressions until now.

I'm trying to generate an extension method to modify the return value of an expression. To be more specific, I'm trying to add an extension method to use when creating AutoMapper maps.

Example map:

```
map.CreateMap<Widget, WidgetModel>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Count, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Count + 1));
```

What I want to do is create an extension method so I don't have to do that `+ 1` everywhere and can just write it as something like:

```
map.CreateMap<Widget, WidgetModel>()
   .Increment(x => x.Count, src => src.Count);
```

And have `Increment()` do the `+ 1` for me.

I've looked around enough to realize that an `ExpressionVisitor` is probably what I need, but I'm not sure where to go from there?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4749576/1346943) seems similar, but I'm not able to translate that work to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Expression.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324052(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than doing a + 1. 
Or we can make it really generic.

Something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var mapperConfiguraiton = 
        new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
            cfg.CreateMap<Widget, WidgetModel>()
               .Increment(x => x.CountD, src => src.Count)
               .ToUpper(x => x.Name, src=>src.Name));

    var widget = new Widget {Count = 3, Name="Jimmy"};
    var mapper = mapperConfiguraiton.CreateMapper();

    var model = mapper.Map<WidgetModel>(widget);
}

public class Widget {
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class WidgetModel {
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public static class MapperExtensions {
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> Increment<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TDestination, int>> destinationMember, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, int>> sourceMember) 
    {
        return expression.CustomAction(destinationMember, sourceMember, s => s + 1);
     }

    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ToUpper<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TDestination, string>> destinationMember, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, string>> sourceMember)
    {
        return expression.CustomAction(destinationMember, sourceMember, s => s.ToUpper());
    }


    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CustomAction<TSource, TDestination, TDestinationMember, TSourceMember>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TDestination, TDestinationMember>> destinationMember, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> sourceMember, 
        Expression<Func<TSourceMember, TDestinationMember>> transform)
    {
       var sourceMemberExpression = (MemberExpression)sourceMember.Body;        
       var sourceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));

       var expr = Expression.Invoke(transform, 
                                Expression
                                    .MakeMemberAccess(sourceParameter, sourceMemberExpression.Member));

        var lambda = (Expression<Func<TSource,TSourceMember>>)
            Expression.Lambda(expr, sourceParameter);

        var newExpression = expression.ForMember(
             destinationMember, 
             opts => opts.MapFrom(lambda));

        return newExpression;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
widget.Count = 3
widget.Name = "Jimmy"

model.Count = 4
model.Name = "JIMMY"
```

Comment: Thanks! What if instead of incrementing an integer result, I wanted to perform some transformation on a string result? For example, let's say I wanted to `ToUpper()` the result from the original expression?

Comment: @SvenGrosen The same idea applies, you'd just change where I've put int to string or whatever value type you are manipulating.

Comment: @SvenGrosen I've made it more generic so you can have custom actions and make your own extension methods

Comment: @SvenGrosen Please mark as answered if it answered your question fully :)