# Create a LinQ Expression with another Expression's Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

> #### Vote my question to be closed
>
> I have found a similar question and a really useful answer using
>   `ExpressionVisitor` class (Link:
>   [How can I convert a lambda-expression between different (but compatible) models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007101/how-can-i-convert-a-lambda-expression-between-different-but-compatible-models#14007103)).
>   Thank you all, I'm voting to my answer become closed as duplicate, please consider voting too.

### Code

I'm developing a repository code that uses a Data Transfer Object, like the code below.

```
public class UsuarioRepositorio : IUsuarioRepository
{
    private readonly MongoRepository<UsuarioDto> _Repository;

    public UsuarioRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _Repositorio = new MongoRepository<UsuarioDto>(connectionString, "");
    }
}

public interface IUsuarioRepository
{  
    IEnumerable<T> Select(Expression<Func<Usuario, bool>> predicate);
}
```

- **UsuarioDto** is the data transfer object for the **Usuario** class, both inheriting from the interface **IUsuario**.
- The **UsuarioRepository** implements the **IUsuarioRepository** interface, and has a private member called _Repository, which belongs to the `MongoRepository<UsuarioDto>` type.
- The **_Repository** member has a method called **Select** which accepts an argument of type `Expression<Func<UsuarioDto, bool>>`.
- The **IUsuarioRepository** has a declared method called **Select** which accepts an argument of type `Expression<Func<Usuario, bool>>`.

### Problem

The problem is that I need to implement the **Select** method in **UsuarioRepository**, using the **IUsuarioRepository** method signature and passing to **_Repository** a new expression of `Expression<Func<UsuarioDto, bool>>` type, with the same parameters of `Expression<Func<Usuario, bool>>` argument.

Basically I need a way to copy the expression parameters to a new expression of different type, knowing that the expressions has the same properties because they have the same interface inheritance. Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Usuario> Select(Expression<Func<Usuario, bool>> predicate)
{
    Expression<Func<UsuarioDto, bool>> transferExpression = x => x != null;
    transferExpression = transferExpression .Update(predicate.Body, predicate.Parameters);

    return _Repository.Select(transferExpression ).ToList().Select(x => x.ToDomain());
}
```

### Questions

- The **Update** method of `Expression` type does work like the code above?
- If it does not work, is there a way to copy expressions of different types, but with the same base/interface properties?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression Tree Copy or Convert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601844/expression-tree-copy-or-convert)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a lambda-expression between different (but compatible) models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007101/how-can-i-convert-a-lambda-expression-between-different-but-compatible-models)

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post about combining 2 expressions of the same type here:
http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2013/07/23/linq-expression-how-to-append-to-an-expression-at-a-later-stage/

all you will need to do to achieve working with 2 types is alter the static methods in my extension class **LambdaExtensions** to work with T, T2 instead of T

a word of warning, if referencing a property of T2 that is not in T1, it may not be successful - you will need to handle this.

I've provided you with a starting point, and I will also be attempting this myself, I will update this answer later - but feel free to try it out yourself so long.