# Combining expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression, iqueryable, func

I have the following expression:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> UserAccessCheckExpression<T>(int userId) where T : class
{
    return x => (IsAdmin || userId == CurrentUserId || userId == 0);
}
```

Then I want to apply this filter to several collections (IQueryable) like this one:

```
return tasks
  .Where(t => t.TaskUsers
     .Any(x => UserAccessCheckExpression<TaskUser>(x.User) && x.SomeBool == true));
```

I'm getting the following error while doing so:

> Error  40  Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TaskUser,bool>>` to `bool`

I can't use workaround with interface inheritance (like TaskUser inherits interface with int UserId property (where T : IHasUserId)) since I want to combine logic.

Comment: You're going to have to manually construct the Lambda somewhat, something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001082/manually-build-linq-expression-for-x-x-child-itemtocompare-child  I don't have enough time to give a full answer.

Comment: You will need to use the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool). And then you'd write something like `t.TaskUsers.Any(UserAccessCheckExpression)`

Comment: What is your Linq provider? Is it Entity Framework? What's `IsAdmin` and `CurrentUserId` in your expression?

Comment: @haim770, it is EF. They are properties of the other class.

Comment: @jeroenvanlangen it is just a contraint for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `UserAccessCheckExpression()` method is returning an `Expression` while the `Any()` method is expecting a `boolean`.

Now, you can get your code to *compile* by compiling the `Expression` and invoking the method (using `UserAccessCheckExpression<TaskUser>(x.User).Compile().Invoke(x.User))` but that would obviously fail on runtime because Linq-to-Entities wouldn't be able to translate your `Any()` to a store query as it no longer contains an `Expression`.

[LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) is aiming to solve this problem using its own `Invoke` extension method that while letting your code compile, will make sure your `Expression` will get replaced back to its original form using another extension method named `AsExpandable()` that is extending the entity set.

Try this:

```
using LinqKit.Extensions;

return tasks
      .AsExpandable()
      .Where(t => t.TaskUsers.Any(
                       x => UserAccessCheckExpression<TaskUser>(x.User).Invoke(x)
                            && x.SomeBool == true));
```

[More on LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: Out of interest, does the extension method thus compile the expression only once?

Comment: @Kolky, Internally, it calls `expr.Compile().Invoke(arg1)` but it never really gets executed. Its only purpose is letting the `Expression` be represented as `Func` *at compile time* while making sure that at runtime the original `Expression` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so, you can't do that. There's a difference between an `Expression<>` and a `Func<>`. You're trying to use the `UserAccessCheckExpression` as a func. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can compile it to a func and then use it sorta like you are:

```
var expr = UserAccessCheckExpression<TaskUser>(x.User);
var func = expr.Compile();
// Later use it like ...
var result = func();
```

But I expect you're using this with EF or Linq2Sql? That being the case you'll need to rewrite the expression. It can be done by hand (not easy) or, better, use a tool like PredicateBuilder.