# Projecting a single record with a static Func<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, projection

I have been using a pattern for projecting from Entity Framework to business domain views. I am nesting it, i.e. calling one projection from within another projection. It works well for collections, but I can't work out how to use the same pattern for projecting a single entity.

For collections, my code looks something like:

```
public class PersonView
{
    public int Id {get;private set;}
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public static Expression<Func<Person, PersonView>> Projector = p => new PersonView {
         Id = p.PersonId,
         FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
    };
}
//...
context.People.Select(PersonView.Projector).ToList();  // returns a list of PersonViews
```

If I create a list containing the 1 element, or otherwise get creative with the LINQ, I can get it to work, but would prefer a neater solution if possible.

```
// convert single element to list, then project it. Works, but is messy
var orderDetails = context.Orders.Where(...)
    .Select(o => new { 
       Id = o.Id, 
       Date = o.Date, 
       PersonView = new [] { o.Person }.AsQueryable().Select(PersonView.Projector).FirstOrDefault()
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like something like (the below does not work, because linq to entities cannot invoke the Func<>):

```
public class PersonView
{
    public int Id {get;private set;}
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public static Func<Person, PersonView> ProjectorFn = p => new PersonView {
         Id = p.PersonId,
         FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
    };        
    public static Expression<Func<Person, PersonView>> ProjectorExpr = p => ProjectorFn(p);
}
 var orderDetails = context.Orders.Where(...)
    .Select(o => new { 
       Id = o.Id, 
       Date = o.Date, 
       PersonView = PersonView.ProjectorFn(o.Person)
}).FirstOrDefault();

//...
var peopleWithOrders = context.People.Where(p => p.Orders.Any())
    .Select(PersonView.ProjectorExpr);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use LinqKit. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36736907/1625737

Comment: I checked it out, but it doesn't seem to relate. I have no issue with nesting .Select's to do an inline projection, however, I want to encapsulate my projection logic into the view class that it returns

Comment: I'll drag myself out of bed to write an answer that'll show you how it *does* relate  (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the problem is that the following line in your projection

```
PersonView = PersonView.ProjectorFn(o.Person)
```

Cannot be translated into a store query because `ProjectorFn` is no longer an `Expression` but a generic delegate (`Func<Person, PersonView>`).

Now, what you actually want is to use the original expression contained in your  `PersonView.Projector` field, but obviously you can't because it cannot be invoked (without compiling to delegate) hence cannot return your desired `PersonView` type.

[LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) is aiming to solve this problem using its own `Invoke()` extension method that while letting your code compile, will make sure your expression gets replaced back to its original form.

To enable the interception, you have to use the `AsExpandable()` method that is extending the entity set:

```
using LinqKit.Extensions;

var orderDetails = context.Orders
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(...)
    .Select(o => new { 
       Id = o.Id, 
       Date = o.Date, 
       PersonView = PersonView.Projector.Invoke(o.Person)
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

[More on LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks! I still need to be careful to not do something like `PersonView = PersonView.Projector.Invoke(o.SomeNavigation.ManyProperties.FirstOrDefault().SubProperty.Person)`, but that's just common sense...

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep using the direct expression tree, but also compile it to a normal delegate:

```
public static readonly Func<Person, PersonView> ProjectorFunc = Projector.Compile();
```

Comment: Link to Entities will throw using the above expression

Comment: As @haim770 said, this still throws an exception- `Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: @AndrewP: Yes; you need to keep using the original expression tree in all LINQ to Entities calls.